# Storing user data from different registration methods: email, mobile and social media

Tags: mysql

Users on a proposed website can sign up in one of 3 ways:

- Using their email address
- Using their mobile number
- Using social media

When storing this information in a MySQL database how is this done?

Storing data in 1 table would result in a lot of NULL columns. The `user` table would have fields for both mobile, and email as well as social media ID's.

Creating separate tables for each type of user would make queries tricky.

Both ways seem incorrect to me. How do you store data for 3 different types of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store users in one table and having type column.And having user details for each type of user. And for each case use detail different tables.And no null values in columns.